# Why doesn't array length view change when new object is added?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects and it's length is displayed like this:

```
<strong *ngIf="cart">{{ cart.length }}</strong>
```

When I add something to it, in the console array and it's length are showing normally, but it's view is not changing, it's still 0.
Here is .ts file:

```
cart=[];
add = (item) => {
  this.cart.push(item);
  console.log(this.cart);
  console.log(this.cart.length);
}
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you add an item in your array like:

```
this.cart.push(item);
```

The cart array reference is not updated => no rerender is triggered
=> That is why it is not updated in your view.

Try adding elements like:

```
this.cart = [...this.cart, newItem];
```

Your view should be updated properly.

Comment: Same thing happens, everything works but view doesn't change.

Comment: ok try modify you add function like: public add() : void {this.cart.push(item);}

Comment: Dont use arrow function to declare method in angular

Comment: how do you call your add method ?

Comment: I just made a stackBlitz that's work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m57pau?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In other component like this:
    public add(item):void{
    this.cart.add(item);
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227170/discussion-between-mr-m-m-and-davidr).